# A comparison of extractors in terms of tradeoffs between time, randomness and space ?

Tags: reference-request, randomness, derandomization

Is there a good survey that compares different extractors, concentrators and superconcentrators and lays out the best methods in terms of the tradeoff between randomness, time and space ?

Comment: Hi Suresh, I don't think extractors and (super)-concentrators are comparable. Perhaps I misread the question, and you meant comparing the construction algorithms?

Parameters for (super)-concentrators that we care about are their depths and sizes, not "randomness, time, and space".

[Radhakrishnan and Ta-shma's paper][1] has a table showing all the tight results (including references) for super-concentrators.

  [1]: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.5.3637

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've never quite understood the differences between them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default reference is Ronen Shaltiel's [survey](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/~ronen/online_papers/survey.ps).  This predates the important results of [Barak-Impagliazzo-Wigderson '04], [Barak-Kindler-Shaltiel-Sudakov-Wigderson '05], [Barak-Rao-Shaltiel-Wigderson '06] etc.  I believe Anup Rao's [Ph.D. thesis](http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/anuprao/pubs/thesis.pdf) is a good recent reference that describes these developments.